# Function testing for primes not working as needed

Tags: python, python-2.7, primes

It's supposed to find out if the given input is a prime number or not.

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x <= 1:
        return False
    elif x == 2 or x == 3:
        return True
    else:
        for n in range(2, x-1):
            if x % n == 0:
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

But

```
is_prime(9)
```

gives `True` where it should return `False`.

I can't find the bug, need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return `True` the moment you find a factor that doesn't divide `x` evenly. `2` doesn't divide `9` so you return `True` then:

```
>>> x = 9
>>> n = 2
>>> if x % n == 0:
...     print False
... else:
...     print True
... 
True
```

You need only return `True` when you determined that no factors exist, so *outside* your loop:

```
for n in range(2, x-1):
    if x % n == 0:
        return False
return True
```

You don't need to test up to `x - 1`, testing up to `int(x ** 0.5) + 1` is enough (so up to the square root):

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x <= 1:
        return False
    if x in (2, 3):
        return True
    for n in range(2, int(x ** 0.5) + 1):
        if x % n == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: This helped a lot. Was stuck for 1 day on this question.